# C++: save variable value for next call of the function

Tags: c++, static, initialization

Is there a way to initialize a variable in a function and save its value for next call of function?

I'm making application in qt and i have one function connected with a signal. I want an variable in that function to change after the other one reaches its goal. Here is the body of that function:

```
void objekt::advance(int phase)
{
if(!phase) return;

QPointF location = this->pos();
if (int(location.x())==200 || int(location.x())==-200)
{
    smijer=-smijer;

}
setPos(mapToParent(smijer,0));
}
```

I defined the smijer variable as static int. But i dont'know how to initialize it only once, when program starts, and how to keep its new value after each call of the function.

Comment: Static variables *are* initialized once only. What's the problem?

Comment: Where to initialize it? In header file? From another class? I tried initialization from another class but i get this error:objekt.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int objekt::smijer" (?smijer@objekt@@2HA)

Comment: you probably should initialize static member of the class inside the class. or move it to the other class and pass the value to this one.

Comment: Is `smijer` a member of class `objekt`?

Comment: Does `smijer` need to be used by other functions?  Do you really want it have global lifetime, not tied to the lifetime of `objekt`?

Answer (score 13):

Your answer is in your question basically. Static variables (either a class member or local variable of a function) is initialized only once where it is terminated. For example;

```
#include <iostream>
int foo () {
   static int sVar = 5;
   sVar++;
   return sVar;
}

using namespace std;
int main () {
   int iter = 0;
   do {
       cout << "Svar :" foo() << endl;
       iter++;
      }while (iter < 3); 
}
```

if you write a program like that it will print out Svar values just like;

```
Svar :6
Svar :7
Svar :8
```

So as you see although we call foo function three times the initialization of a static varible is done only once.

Answer (score 1):

If `smijer` is a member of class `objekt`, then do it like this:

objekt.h:

```
class objekt
{
   ...
   static int smijer;
   ...
};
```

objekt.cpp

```
int objekt::smijer = YOUR_INITIALIZATION_VALUE;
```

On the other hand, if you want/need `smijer` to be a global variable, then do it like this:

globals.h:

```
extern int smijer;
```

globals.cpp //Or another .cpp file

```
int smijer = YOUR_INITIALIZATION_VALUE;
```

Although in this case I'd stick it in a namespace.  In this case it isn't declared static but it does have the lifetime of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Why am I being downvoted? He wants to change a variable and preserve the states after function calls. (He doesn't specify whether the variable is a member of the class or anything, so I'm assuming it's not. I'll change my answer if he clarifies and states his question less ambiguously.)

You're going about this wrong. To keep a variable after a function's scope ends, you have to allocate it on the heap rather than the stack. You can use `new` or `malloc` to do this, but you also have to free this memory with `delete` and `free`, in that order.

With `new` and `delete`:

```
#include <iostream>

void modify(int * p){
    (*p)++;
}

int main(void){
    int * pointer = new int;
    *pointer = 5;

    std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;

    modify(pointer);

    std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;

    delete pointer;
    return 0;
}
```

And with `malloc` and `free`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

void modify(int * p){
    (*p)++;
}

int main(void){
    int * pointer = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)); //DO NOT CAST IN C
    *pointer = 5;

    std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;

    modify(pointer);

    std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;

    free(pointer);
    return 0;     
}
```

`new` does provide facilities for deleting arrays quickly and is better overall for normal use C++.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as static inside the function and the valued will be remembered. You don't need to initialize it. But you can if you want to.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, why? What do you mean?

Comment: @MattPhillips That is not a function-level `static` variable.  You've confused it with a `static` member variable, which is completely different.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes, I realized I misinterpreted the answer but somehow my comment to that effect got deleted.  However I think OP wants something with more than function-level scope.